# Refer to the Expando object when adding a new property?

Tags: groovy

The following example is from listing 7.22 of the book Groovy in Action (2007):

```
def boxer = new Expando()
assert null == boxer.takeThis
boxer.takeThis = 'ouch!'
assert 'ouch!' == boxer.takeThis
boxer.fightBack = {times -> return this.takeThis * times }
assert 'ouch!ouch!ouch!' == boxer.fightBack(3)
```

I put the code into a script `hello.groovy`. When I ran it, I got the following error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: takeThis for class: hello
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: takeThis for class: hello
    at hello$_run_closure1.doCall(hello.groovy:5)
    at hello.run(hello.groovy:6)
```

Apparently, the `this` in line 5 is not referring to the `boxer` object but to the script. So, what is the right way to add the `fightBack` property to the Expando `boxer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `this` with `delegate`.

`this` refers to the script (as you mentioned), `delegate` refers to the caller on which the closure is invoked.

You could get the difference in usage of `this`, `delegate` and `owner` [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures).